# Download other user dropbox file without my dropbox token

Tags: python, dropbox

To download other user dropbox file i use

```
with open("rc.xlsx", "wb") as f:
    shared_link = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/xx/xx.xlsx?dl=0"
    metadata, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url=shared_link,link_password ='xxxx')
    f.write(res.content)
```

Even so this is not my file i still need mydropbox token to download it. Is it possible to avoid it ?

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(mydropbox_token)
```

Comment: Not familiar with the dropbox API but I'm guessing no. You need to tell dropbox who _you_ are before it allows you to download a shared file.

Comment: @rdas Yes, make sense but either way you don't need to be registered to dropbox at all to download this file

Comment: Try using simple `requests` instead of the Dropbox SDK then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Dropbox Python SDK tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial),

> In order to make calls to the API, you'll need an instance of the
> Dropbox object. To instantiate, pass in the access token for the
> account you want to link.

So, the access token is necessary for creating an object of the `Dropbox` class.

In the [example of `dropbox` API](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/back-up-and-restore/backup-and-restore-example.py#L78), they also show that the access token is mandatory.

**References:**

- [Dropbox Python SDK tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial)
- [example of `dropbox` API](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/back-up-and-restore/backup-and-restore-example.py#L78)